# Ignoring text when converting strings of text to numbers

Tags: string-manipulation, data, number-representation

I have a string of measurements--mostly numbers, but occasionally an NA. Right now *Mathematica* is reading it all as text, so I'm using

```
Read[StringToStream[#], Number] & /@ z;
```

to convert to a number string, where z is the string.

Is there a way to skip the NA whenever it appears?

Edit: the numbers are all in scientific notation (2.00E-07)

Sample string:

```
{NA,NA,NA,2.05E-08,2.07E-06,3.45E-09,7.52E-07,NA,NA...}
```

Comment: Can you post a sample string?

Comment: Why not just remove the NA afterwards, `DeleteCases[z, NA]`?

Comment: You sample string is not a string. Please put some effort in that :)

Answer (score 1):

Using the three-argument form of [`Interpreter`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpreter.html) to provide a default value (here, [`Indeterminate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indeterminate.html)) in case of failure:

```
int = Interpreter["Number", Not@*FailureQ, Indeterminate &];

s = "{NA,NA,NA,2.05E-08,2.07E-06,3.45E-09,7.52E-07,NA,NA}";
int /@ StringSplit[s, {"{", "}", ","}]

(*    {Indeterminate, Indeterminate, Indeterminate, 2.05*10^-8, 
       2.07*10^-6, 3.45*10^-9, 7.52*10^-7, Indeterminate,
       Indeterminate}                                              *)
```

Any default value can be picked, for example [`Nothing`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nothing.html):

```
int2 = Interpreter["Number", Not@*FailureQ, Nothing &];
int2 /@ StringSplit[s, {"{", "}", ","}]
(*    {2.05*10^-8, 2.07*10^-6, 3.45*10^-9, 7.52*10^-7}    *)
```

[See also this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/284654/26598) for an attempt to set up an `Interpreter` for the entire string, but failing due to a possible bug.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume this is your `z`:

```
z = List["NA", "NA", "NA", "2.05E-08", "2.07E-06", "3.45E-09", "7.52E-07", "NA", "NA"]
```

You could remove the "NA" before interpreting the numbers:

```
zClean = DeleteCases[z, "NA"]
```

A simpler string-to-number mechanism might be `Interpreter`:

```
Interpreter["Number"] /@ zClean
```

It might be better to clean the data afterward, however, because there may be other failure modes:

```
DeleteCases[Interpreter["Number"] /@ z, _Failure]
```

Answer (score 0):

As much as I understood you, initially you have a list of strings, rather than a list of numbers. If this is right, try this:

```
str = {"NA", "NA", "NA", "2.05E-08", "2.07E-06", "3.45E-09", 
  "7.52E-07", "NA", "NA"}

Map[ToExpression[StringJoin[#]] &, 
 Map[Characters, str /. "NA" -> Nothing] /. "E" -> "*10^"]

(* {2.05*10^-8, 2.07*10^-6, 3.45*10^-9, 7.52*10^-7} *)
```

Let us check

```
Head /@ lst

(*  {Real, Real, Real, Real}   *)
```

Thus, now you have a list of numbers and can operate them in Mma.

Have fun!