# Bug in Interpreter with DelimitedSequence and alternatives?

Tags: import, interpreter

In the context of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/190114/26598) I tried setting up an interpreter that converts a string to a list of numbers, while converting `"NA"` to `Indeterminate`. My attempted solution works in general, but fails on the first iteration:

```
Exit[]   (* make sure to start with a fresh kernel *)

$Version
(*    "13.2.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (November 18, 2022)"    *)

int = Interpreter[DelimitedSequence["Number" | {"NA" -> Indeterminate}, {"{", ",", "}"}]];

s = "{NA,NA,NA,2.05E-08,2.07E-06,3.45E-09,7.52E-07,NA,NA}";

int[s]
(*    Interpreter[DelimitedSequence["Number" | {"NA" -> Indeterminate}, {"{", ",", "}"}]][
          "{NA,NA,NA,2.05E-08,2.07E-06,3.45E-09,7.52E-07,NA,NA}"]    *)

int[s]
(*    {Indeterminate, Indeterminate, Indeterminate, 2.05*10^-8, 
       2.07*10^-6, 3.45*10^-9, 7.52*10^-7, Indeterminate, Indeterminate}    *)

int[s]
(*    {Indeterminate, Indeterminate, Indeterminate, 2.05*10^-8,
       2.07*10^-6, 3.45*10^-9, 7.52*10^-7, Indeterminate, Indeterminate}    *)
```

Is this a bug? Why else would an `Interpreter` fail on first use, then work fine for all subsequent uses?

### update: a minimal example

Thanks to @BenIzd!

```
Exit[]   (*make sure to start with a fresh kernel*)

Interpreter["Number" | {"NA"}]["1"]
(*    Interpreter["Number" | {"NA"}]["1"]    *)

Interpreter["Number" | {"NA"}]["1"]
(*    1    *)
```

Comment: Works on the first and subsequent uses. I am running v12.2.0 on Win7-x64 .

Comment: Same for me; works the first and all subsequent uses (12.3.1 Win and 13.0.0 Win and 13.2.0. Wolfram Cloud).

Comment: Same for me. 13.2 on Windows 10

Comment: On my setup Windows 11, Mathematica 13.2.1, If I put `int = ...; int["1"]` in one cell it returns unevaluated but if they were separate it works fine. I think a better example would be the following `Interpreter["Number" | {"NA"}]["1"]` which returns unevaluated for the first time (fresh kernel) but works as expected on subsequent calls.

Comment: Thanks @BenIzd, I've updated the minimal example.