# Simple definite integral returns useless answer

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I tried to run

```
  Integrate[   (E^(I q x))/(q - I), {q, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
  Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals]
```

I got something involving MeijerG function whereas the answer is really simple viz.

```
  E^-x (2 \[Pi] I) HeavisideTheta[x]
```

Comment: FWIW: FourierTransform gives you that result basically instantly: `Sqrt[2 Pi] * FourierTransform[1/(q - I), q, x]`

Comment: I think F.T. is the way to go. But to get the `x>0` part, you can do `anti = Integrate[(E^(I q x))/(q - I), q];
hi = Limit[anti, q -> Infinity, Assumptions -> x > 0];
low = Limit[anti, q -> -Infinity, Assumptions -> x > 0];
anti = hi - low` which gives `2 I Pi Exp[-x]` but for x<0, it does not give zero.  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asICs.png)  F.T. does some magic internally.  Maple 2023 gives ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Stpa.png) which match the result from F.T.

Comment: There are many kinds of integrals in mathematics. `FourierTransform[]` computes a different class than `Integrate[]`. I'm not sure that the classes are well-defined in Mma, but `DiracDelta[]` and `HeavisideTheta[]` (at least as a distribution) are not possible answers in classical analysis. E.g. the classical integral $\int_{\Bbb R} Exp[i q x] \, dq$ diverges. Also, `FourierTransform[]` uses a different lookup table, and therefore it is more likely to be successful when you wish to compute Fourier transforms. This distinction in functionality should be kept in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `FourierTransform`

```
 FourierTransform[1/(q - I), q, x] 
 (*2 I E^-x \[Pi] HeavisideTheta[x]*)
```

Comment: This means it is well within capabilities of Mathematica. Why does the integral form give a useless answer then? Something for the makers to fix. This is an extremely critical integral in all branches of physics and engineering. It is unacceptable that the integral gives a complicated answer.

Comment: **It is unacceptable that the integral gives a complicated answer** Ok, this result was complicated, I agree. (but I assume it is correct, did not verify). But Mathematica still solves more integrals that any other CAS system out there.  No software is perfect !

Comment: There are many even simpler examples where F.T. gives a result: ` FourierTransform[1 , q, x]  (*Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] DiracDelta[x]*)`  whereas `Integrate[(E^(I q x)) , {q, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
 Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals]` doesn't evaluate

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Arguably, though, that integral is not actually well-defined and shouldn't be returned as a result from `Integrate`. But for something straight-forward like the Fourier transform of `1/(1 + q^2)` there is no excuse.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Here the "excuse": Mathematica 12.2  evaluates `Integrate[(E^(I q x))/(1 + q^2) , {q, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]  (*ConditionalExpression[Pi/E^Abs[x], Element[x, Reals]]*)`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Actually, I just found out that `Integrate` does the transform of `1/(1+q^2)` correctly most of the time, but sometimes in a fresh kernel it returns some horrible `MeijerG` thing. Must be some loading-order thing.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit So you are saying it is a bug, i.e. antiderivate is total malarkey? But yeah integrating in reals gives correct result.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit this is the second time I see a loading-order problem (the other one being [this Interpreter bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/284654/26598). Maybe file a bug report and link the issues?

Answer (score 5):

It also works by integrating real and imaginary parts separately:

```
Integrate[(q Cos[q x])/(1 + q^2) - Sin[q x]/(1 + q^2), {q, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]},
  Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals]
(* 0 *)

Integrate[(Cos[q x]/(1 + q^2) + (q Sin[q x])/(1 + q^2)), {q, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
  Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals]
(* E^-Abs[x] \[Pi] (1 + Sign[x]) *)
```

Comment: Similarly, `Integrate[ComplexExpand[(E^(I q x))/(q - I)], {q, -∞, ∞}, Assumptions -> x > 0]` returns `2 I E^-x π`, and the same input with `Assumptions -> x < 0` returns `0`.  But `Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals` returns an ugly result.

Comment: Is MeijerG result for both then?